# Accessing super class instance variable

Tags: java

Experts I need a bit of help here to understand what I am not able to understand. I am creating a super class and a sub class, I am trying to access the super class instance variable through subclass, but I always get null. Unless I explicitly assign value to the 'name' variable in super class.

```
package example1;

public class InterfaceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.printinfo("WOLFSKIN", "Test Address");
        Boy boy = new Boy();
        boy.info();
    }
}

class Person {
    String name;
    String address;

    public void printinfo(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + '\n' + "Address: " + address);
    }
}

class Boy extends Person {
    public void info() {
        System.out.println("Subclass Name " + this.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: What can't you understand? You didn't declare any value for the name so it is just normal that it returns null...

Comment: You haven't set any value to `boy.name` field, so it is null. The `person` and `boy` instances are completely unrelated, don't know about each other.

Comment: I got it from the below answer (T.J. Crowder), I was assuming the instance of subclass would inherit the super class instance (instance values) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You never assign any value to `name` in your `Boy` instance, I've added some explanatory comments:

```
// Creates a Person (not a Boy)
Person person = new Person();

// Sets the name on that Person
person.printinfo("WOLFSKIN", "Test Address");

// Creates an *entirely separate object*, an instance of Boy
Boy boy = new Boy();

// Accesses `name`, which has never been set
boy.info();
```

To set `name` on your `Boy` instance, call `printinfo` on your `Boy` instance:

```
boy.printinfo("WOLFSKIN", "Test Address");
```

Let's throw some ASCII-art at it:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

gives us:

```
+-----------+     +-----------------+
|   person  |---->| Person instance |
+-----------+     +-----------------+
                  | name: null      |
+-----------+     | address: null   |
| boy: null |     +-----------------+
+-----------+
```

Then after:

```
person.printinfo("WOLFSKIN", "Test Address");
```

We have:

```
+--------+       +-----------------+    +-----------------+
| person |------>| Person instance |    | String instance |
+--------+       +-----------------+    +-----------------+
                 | name            |--->| "WOLFSKIN"      |
                 | address         |-+  +-----------------+
                 +-----------------+ |
+-----------+                        |  +-----------------+
| boy: null |                        |  | String instance |
+-----------+                        |  +-----------------+
                                     +->| "Test Address"  |
                                        +-----------------+
```

Now we do:

```
Boy boy = new Boy();
```

And get this:

```
+--------+       +-----------------+    +-----------------+
| person |------>| Person instance |    | String instance |
+--------+       +-----------------+    +-----------------+
                 | name            |--->| "WOLFSKIN"      |
                 | address         |-+  +-----------------+
                 +-----------------+ |
+-----------+                        |  +-----------------+
| boy       |-+                      |  | String instance |
+-----------+ |                      |  +-----------------+
              |                      +->| "Test Address"  |
              |                         +-----------------+
              |  +-----------------+
              +->| Boy instance    |
                 +-----------------+
                 | name: null      |
                 | address: null   |
                 +-----------------+
```

Note that the Boy instance is made up of the fields of its superclasses (`Person`, in this case) as well as its own fields (but it doesn't have any).

Since you've never filled in a value for `boy`'s `name`, it still has the default `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `name` from an instance of `Boy`, but it's been assigned in an instance of `Person`, hence it's `null`.

You can obviate that by adding:

```
boy.printinfo("WOLFSKIN", "Test Address");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you appear to think that `this` returns the instance of your super class, when it actually returns the instance of the class it is in. In your example, `this` refers to your `Boy` class and its fields, when you seem to want it to refer to `Person`. `Boy` does not have the same `name` as `Person` unless you add:

```
Boy boy = new Boy();
boy.name = person.name;
boy.info();
```

I am not an expert on this, but I believe you could also do, in your `info()` method:

```
this.name = super.name;
System.out.println("Subclass Name " + this.name);
```

You may need to make `name` a static variable in `Person` if you use the second approach, but I am not sure (if anyone knows please edit/comment). It is probably safer to use the first one, because then you can have multiple instances of `Boy` each with a different name. Anyone reading this who knows more or knows if I am incorrect in any of this, please edit/comment any corrections.